# How long do helmets last?

Tags: helmets

Assume there's no visible damage to a bicycle helmet and it's been under normal use (2000-4000 miles/year).

When would you replace it? After 3 years? 5? not at all assuming it seems visibly OK?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @zbicyclist. Nice comments in your profile :-) The next thing to do is take the [tour] so that you can make best use of the site, and since you're asking, [ask] is worthwhile also. We think the answers to the question that's suggested as a duplicate will help you. If not, edit your question to explain what's different. Good to see you here

Comment: A lot depends on the use.  Stored in a box on a shelf a helmet should last at least 10 years.  Used daily and hung outdoors from the handlebar when not being worn, I'd guess two years.

Answer (score 2):

Five to eight years seems reasonable.  See here: http://www.helmets.org/replace.htm - some helmet makers recommend somewhere in this range, and longer than eight years you start to see deterioration from sun damage, occasional knocks, etc.

My last helmet lasted only four years in high-UV riding, about 15,000 km total, before the plastic strap around the back simply cracked in half.  This didn't make it 100% useless or ineffective, but it surely prompted replacement.  But this was a lot of riding, mostly in bright sun and high temperatures.